# How to sort listview items by numeric values column in android

Tags: android, sorting, android-listview

I have a listview lv with the following items in it:

```
Hyda, 25.00
Bran, 11.75
Geda, 2.55
```

I would like to sort the items by the second column so that the Listview will show:

```
Geda, 2.55
Bran, 11.75
Hyda, 25.00
```

The code I am using below sorts only by the first column; i.e it returns:

```
Bran, 11.75
Geda, 2.55
Hyda, 25.00

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

        lv = rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvData);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

        list.add("Hyda"+", "+"25.00");
        list.add("Bran"+", "+"11.75");
        list.add("Geda"+", "+"2.55");


        lv.setAdapter(adapter);


        btnSort = rootView.findViewById(R.id.sortButton);
        btnSort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Collections.sort(list,new myComparatorNumbers());
                for (String i:list){
                   lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }                
            }
        });

        private class myComparatorNumbers implements Comparator<String> {

        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
```

Can anyone help on how to sort it by the second column, i.e by the numeric values? Most of the solutions I found focus on one column data array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like my older answer couldn't help you, I am adding the full implementation now. It should definitely help you

```
class User {
    String name;
    double score;

    User(String name, double score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button sortButton = findViewById(R.id.sortButton);
        ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.lvData);

        List<User> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(new User("Bran", 11.75));
        data.add(new User("Geda", 2.55));
        data.add(new User("Hyda", 25.00));

        final UsersAdapter adapter = new UsersAdapter(this, data);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        sortButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.sortLvData();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Custom Adapter class

```
class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {

    UsersAdapter(@NonNull Context context, List<User> users) {
        super(context, 0, users);
    }

    void sortLvData() {
        sort(new Comparator<User>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(User u1, User u2) {
                return Double.compare(u1.score, u2.score);
            }
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        User user = getItem(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
        //you can even use your custom XML layout to better display the UI.
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        }
        String text = user.name + ", " + user.score;
        ((TextView) convertView).setText(text);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Karan. Could you check the curl brackets? It does have some issues with it

Comment: Oh, Adding the missing parenthesis, I even improved my answer. Thanks!

Comment: It still not working.  For using the class Person, the ArrayAdapter<String> doesn't work. When I use Adapter<Person>, the new adapter requires a different list, say list2. In my view, it was not about the missing parenthesis. There seem to be a conflict of declaration <String> vs <Person>

Comment: I've added the complete implementation of the code. Just tell me if you still face any issue in understanding the code.